# How can I render a string with proper formatting in Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have made a table using the [tabular library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tabular). The table I made using this library is really just a fancy string with lots of newline breaks. The only way that I have figured out how to get this table to format correctly is by using putStr in a repl.

If I just show the string I am returned a mess that looks something like this:

```
"+-----++-----------+-----------++-------------+-------------+\n|     || memtest 1 | memtest 2 || time test 1 | time test 2 |\n+=====++=
```

What I wish to do is to be able to render this table with correct formatting within a Yesod `Handler Html`. More specifically I would like to render this table from within a whamlet template.

I have tried to incorporate the [pretty-printing library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pretty) by using functions such as `pShow` but could not find success. I have looked through various Yesod libraries but can not seem to pin down any functions that are of help.

Comment: Why don't you use proper HTML facilities for generating your tables, instead of going through monospace plaintext? — One easy hack for getting there is just [`intercalate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html#v:intercalate)ing the [`lines`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:lines) of the string with `<br>`, and using the result as a [`preEscapedString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-markup-0.8.2.7/docs/Text-Blaze.html#v:preEscapedString).

Comment: Reading the `tabular` description: `It also comes with some default rendering functions for turning those tables into ... HTML`. So, instead of rendering your table into ASCII, just render it into proper HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two options would seem to be to render the ASCII table as-is using an HTML `<pre>` element for an "old-school" look, or re-render the table using `tabular`'s support for HTML, to get an actual HTML `<table>` element.

The easiest is to render using a `<pre>` element.  In a whamlet template, just interpolate the ASCII table into the template:

```
import Yesod
import qualified Text.Tabular as T
import qualified Text.Tabular.AsciiArt as TA

example = T.Table
  (T.Group T.NoLine [T.Header "1", T.Header "2"])
  (T.Group T.SingleLine [T.Header "Table Type", T.Header "HTML Element"])
  [ ["ASCII art", "<pre>"], ["HTML", "<table>"] ]

asciiTable :: String
asciiTable = TA.render id id id example

getAsciiR :: Handler Html
getAsciiR = defaultLayout
  [whamlet|
    <p>My old-school table follows
    <pre>#{asciiTable}
    |]
```

Using `tabular`'s HTML support is a little complicated, mostly because it uses `Text.Html` and hand-built CSS, which don't directly interface with Yesod's widgets and blaze-based markup.  But, you can build a widget from scratch like so:

```
import Yesod
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.Builder as B
import qualified Text.Tabular as T
import qualified Text.Tabular.AsciiArt as TA
import qualified Text.Tabular.Html as TH
import qualified Text.Html as H

htmlTable :: Widget
htmlTable = do
  toWidget . preEscapedToMarkup . renderHtml $ tbl
  toWidget . CssBuilder . B.fromString $ TH.defaultCss
  where tbl = TH.render H.stringToHtml H.stringToHtml H.stringToHtml example
        renderHtml h = foldr ($) "" [H.renderHtml' 0 e | e <- H.getHtmlElements h]
```

and then interpolate it into a whamlet template using widget interpolation (`^{...}`):

```
getHtmlR :: Handler Html
getHtmlR = defaultLayout
  [whamlet|
    <p>My fancy table follows:
    ^{htmlTable}
    |]
```

which will give something like:

[image]

Full code follows.  You can visit `localhost:3000/ascii` and `localhost:3000/html` to see the results:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}

module TableServer where

import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.Builder as B
import qualified Text.Tabular as T
import qualified Text.Tabular.AsciiArt as TA
import qualified Text.Tabular.Html as TH
import qualified Text.Html as H

import Yesod

data Site = Site
mkYesod "Site" [parseRoutes|
  /ascii AsciiR GET
  /html  HtmlR  GET
  |]
instance Yesod Site

example = T.Table
  (T.Group T.NoLine [T.Header "1", T.Header "2"])
  (T.Group T.SingleLine [T.Header "Table Type", T.Header "HTML Element"])
  [ ["ASCII art", "<pre>"], ["HTML", "<table>"] ]

asciiTable :: String
asciiTable = TA.render id id id example

getAsciiR :: Handler Html
getAsciiR = defaultLayout
  [whamlet|
    <p>My old-school table follows
    <pre>#{asciiTable}
    |]

htmlTable :: Widget
htmlTable = do
  toWidget . preEscapedToMarkup . renderHtml $ tbl
  toWidget . CssBuilder . B.fromString $ TH.defaultCss
  where tbl = TH.render H.stringToHtml H.stringToHtml H.stringToHtml example
        renderHtml h = foldr ($) "" [H.renderHtml' 0 e | e <- H.getHtmlElements h]

getHtmlR :: Handler Html
getHtmlR = defaultLayout
  [whamlet|
    <p>My fancy table follows:
    ^{htmlTable}
    |]

main :: IO ()
main = warp 3000 Site
```